# How do I find the following limits with L'Hospital?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limits at $0$ and infinity of the following function:

> $$f(x):=\ln(3^x-1)-\ln(2^x-1)$$

where $x$ is bigger than $0$. I have to use *L'Hospital Rule* but I am just getting a harder limit when I apply it. *Can you say what to do?*

Comment: can you write the function with only on $ln$ term?

Comment: You mean if we can write $ln\frac{3^x-1}{2^x-1}$? I think yes as soon as the domain remains the same for x.

Comment: Maybe look at $e^{f(x)}$?If you know that limit you can find the limit of $f(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean? How can I find the limit of f(x) by knowing the limit of $e^{f(x)}$?

Comment: Well $\lim e^{f(x)}=e^{\lim f(x)}$(because of continuity)

Comment: Duplicate?? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216426/how-can-i-find-the-limit-using-lhospital

Comment: @EthanBolker Not at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write,

$$e^{f(x)}=\frac{3^x-1}{2^x-1}$$

Now use L'hospitals  rule on the right hand side. To get,

$$e^{f(x)} \to \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$$

So,

$$e^{\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)}=\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \ln (\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2})$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \ln { \left( \frac { { 3 }^{ x }-1 }{ { 2 }^{ x }-1 }  \right)  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \ln { \left( \frac { { 3 }^{ x }\ln { 3 }  }{ { 2 }^{ x }\ln { 2 }  }  \right)  }  } =\ln { \left( \log _{ 2 }{ 3 }  \right)  } $$

Answer (score 1):

Exponential functions grow fast.

When $x$ is large $a^x$ grows faster than any polynomial function.  At least it does if $a>1$

As $x$ gets to be big, $2^x - 1$ increasingly starts to resemble $2^x$ and the constant term becomes a triviality.

$\ln(3^x -1) - \ln (2^x - 1)$ starts to look like $\ln 3^x - \ln 2^x = x(\ln 3 - \ln 2)$

And as $x$ goes to infinity $x(\ln 3 - \ln 2)$ goes to infinity, too.

Now this may feel a bit hand-wavy.  If we wanted to be more rigorous we would show that as $x$ gets to be large $|(\ln (3^x - 1) - \ln (2^x-1)) - x (\ln 3 - \ln 2)|$ is small.

Or, for any $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists and $N > 0$ such that $x> N$ implies
$|(\ln (3^x - 1) - \ln (2^x-1)) - x (\ln 3 - \ln 2)|<\epsilon$

But, I don't think that that is really necessary.