# How can I find the limit using L'Hospital?

Tags: limits

How can I find the limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2^x+1)}{\ln(3^x+1)}$$

with L'Hospital?

I tried to derivate over and over but I can not get rid of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: Well if I did not do it wrong I get $\frac{2^xln2(3^x+1)}{3^xln3(2^x+1)}$.

Comment: Duplicate?? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216405/how-do-i-find-the-following-limits-with-lhospital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \ln { \left( { 2 }^{ x }+1 \right)  }  }{ \ln { \left( { 3 }^{ x }+1 \right)  }  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \left( { 3 }^{ x }+1 \right) { 2 }^{ x }\ln { 2 }  }{ \left( { 2 }^{ x }+1 \right) { 3 }^{ x }\ln { 3 }  }  } =\frac { \ln { 2 }  }{ \ln { 3 }  } \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { { 6 }^{ x }\left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ 3^{ x } }  \right)  }{ { 6 }^{ x }\left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ 2^{ x } }  \right)  }  } =\log _{ 3 }{ 2 } $$

Comment: Oh, thank you for correction:)

Answer (score 2):

The ratio of the derivatives is $$\dfrac{\dfrac{2^x \ln 2}{2^x + 1}}{\dfrac{3^x \ln 3}{3^x + 1}}.$$ This simplifies to $$\frac{2^x (3^x + 1)}{3^x (2^x + 1)} \cdot \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}.$$
You can evaluate the  limit of the first fraction by first multiplying by $\dfrac{6^{-x}}{6^{-x}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked for, but it might be easier to do without L'Hopital:

$$\begin{align}\log(2^x+1)&=\log(2^x)+\log(1+2^{-x})=x\log(2)+\log(1+2^{-x})\\
\log(3^x+1)&=\log(3^x)+\log(1+3^{-x})=x\log(3)+\log(1+3^{-x})\end{align}$$

So $$\frac{\log(2^x+1)}{\log(3^x+1)} = \frac{x\log 2 + \log(1+2^{-x})}{x\log 3+\log(1+3^{-x})}$$

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x$ you get:

$$\frac{\log 2+ \frac{\log(1+2^{-x})}{x}}{\log 3+\frac{\log(1+3^{-x})}{x}}$$

But $\log(1+3^{-x})$ and $\log(1+2^{-x})$ converge to $0$, and hence so do $\frac{\log(1+2^{-x})}{x}$ and$\frac{\log(1+3^{-x})}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Why use L'Hopital? As $2^x + 1 \sim 2^x$ as $x \to \infty$ and $3^x + 1 \sim 3^x$ as $x \to \infty$.

$$\frac{\ln\left(2^x+1\right)}{\ln\left(3^x+1\right)} \ \sim \ \frac{\ln\left(2^x\right)}{\ln\left(3^x\right)} \ = \ \frac{x\ln 2}{x \ln 3} \ = \ \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}$$

Comment: To a calculus student the $\sim$ represents a step that should not by bypassed.